# UICollectionView cell reuse and online images

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to understand just how UICollectionView cell reuse works.

I am currently implementing a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView with large cells that take up almost the full size of the screen. There are about 100+ cells but you will only ever see ~3 at a time.

As I understand it UICollectionView cell reuse simply maintains a pool of initialized cell objects that way when one cell is out of view it can be cannibalized by a newly viewable cell. That is to say since I am using reuse the collection might only initialize ~3 actual cell objects in memory and I just will switch out their contents.

I am very worried about what this means in the case of custom cells that have image views that are based on images that need to be downloaded. Ideally I would have a scenario where every cells image is only ever downloaded once and it is only downloaded when absolutely necessary.

If there is truly a pool of my custom cell objects then this means that that is totally not happening. As each time a cell comes into view I am starting a completely new download.

How am I supposed to do this right?

The main reason I am asking this is that when scrolling (especially on the initial scroll) I do see some flickering between an image of an old cell and the image the cell is supposed to be displaying. I made a fix but I am fairly sure that it is causing the online images to be downloaded too many times. Am I doing this right?

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell else {
        assert(false)
    }
    let image = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.display(title: image.title, imageURL: image.imageURL)
    return cell
}
```

And the cell

```
public class NewsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private var title: UILabel = UILabel()
    private var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override public init(frame: CGRect = CGRect.zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
        title.textColor = UIColor.white
        title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.addSubview(title)

    // Layout constraints
    }

    public func display(title: String, imageURL: URL?) {
        self.imageView.image = nil
        self.title.text = title
        if let url = imageURL {
            downloadImage(from: url)
        }
    }

    func downloadImage(from url: URL) {
        getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }

    func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }

}
```

I am worried by the fact that I have to set the image views image to nil on display in order to prevent the flicker. Should I be doing something differently to avoid frivolous downloading of these images or does this look good?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Prefetching Collection View Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data) to load your images earlier.

> You use data prefetching when loading data is a slow or expensive process—for example when fetching data over the network. In these circumstances, perform data loading asynchronously.

It will require some changes of course. You will have to store your images separately and download them when `DataSourcePrefetching` method will be called. Also, then the image is downloaded, you'll need to check if there is any cell that waiting for that image. So your `UICollectionView` won't download anything anymore. It will show the image only, or waiting for it to be downloaded.

2. There is a problem with your current solution. If you'll scroll too fast, you make face a situation when because of reusing, the same `UICollectionViewCell` is loading a few images at once. And in this case, the user will see only the last one, and you never can tell which one it would be. To avoid this race condition, you can store the image identifier or its `URL` in the cell so after downloading is finished, it could check if the downloaded image is the right one.
3. It's okay to set `image` to nil while it's downloading, but you also can show to the user some `UIActivityIndicatorView` so he could see that some work is happening.